# python aiogram how to stop an asynchronous loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram

Simple example

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
token = 'token'

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='stoploop')
async def stop_loop(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    #  TODO how to stop test loop?

    await query.message.edit_text('stop')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='test')
async def start_loop(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    a = 100
    while True:
        a -= 1
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('<<<Stop And Back To Home', callback_data='stoploop'))
        await query.message.edit_text(str(a),reply_markup=markup)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start_cmd_handler(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('start loop', callback_data='test')
    )
    await message.reply('test', reply_markup=markup)


async def main():
    try:
        await dp.start_polling()
    finally:
        await bot.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I click start_loop, the tg message box on my page starts to display a countdown. When I click stop, how can I stop the previous countdown?
I use id(query) to confirm that the query instance sent twice is not the same. After I execute the stop_loop function, start_loop will still execute and change the content of the message.
Can someone tell me how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I used redis to solve it, but I don't know if this is the most appropriate way. If there is a more suitable way, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

To manage your loop you should take it outside the handlers and just get in from any storage (dict is used for example).

Basic example of the loop

```py
loops = {}


class Loop:
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self._active = False
        self._stopped = True
        loops[self.user_id] = self
    
    @classmethod
    def get_loop(cls, user_id):
        return loops.get(user_id, cls(user_id))

    @property
    def is_running(self):
        return not self._stopped
        
    async def start(self):
        self._active = True
        asyncio.create_task(self._run_loop())
        
    async def _run_loop(self):
        while self._active:
            await bot.send_message(self.user_id, 'loop is running')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        self._stopped = True
    
    async def stop(self):
        self._active = False
        while not self._stopped:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

So then:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='start')
async def start_loop(query: CallbackQuery):
    user = query.from_user
    loop = Loop.get_loop(user.id)
    
    if loop.is_running:
        return await query.answer('Loop is already running')
    
    loop.start()
    await query.answer('Started!')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='stop')
async def stop_loop(query: CallbackQuery):
    user = query.from_user
    loop = Loop.get_loop(user.id)
    await query.answer('Stopping...')
    await loop.stop()
    await bot.send_message(user.id, 'Loop successfully stopped.')
```